# Logging QSqlDatabase raw queries

Tags: c++, qt, qsqlquery, qsqldatabase

How can I get/log all raw sql queries sent to database by QSqlDatabase?

Does QSqlDatabase have any methods or events?
Something like this:

```
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database(connection->connectionUuid.toString());

    // === SOMETHING LIKE THIS! ===
    db->setLogger([](const QString query) {
        qDebug() << "Query: " << query;
    });
    // = OR =
    connect(db, &QSqlDatabase::QueryExecuted, this, [](const QString query) {
        qDebug() << "Query: " << query;
    });
    // =================

    QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel();
    model->setQuery("SHOW VARIABLES;", db);
    model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Variable"));
    model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Session"));
    model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Global"));
    ui->tblViewVariables->setModel(model);
```

I haven't found any events or somethig else in docs of QSqlDatabase and QSqlDriver classes...

Comment: Reinventing the wheel? MySQL has [The General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html) which also can be storaged in a table instead of a file..

Comment: What about `QSqlDriver::subscribeToNotification()`? You can subscribe to a particular notification and get it logged.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I need log in my application.

Comment: @vahancho, what event should i subscribe to?

Comment: @Alex_Crack, I don't know. It depends from what you want to log and your Sql driver.

Comment: @vahancho, notification is another thing. It's about handling events FROM database. DB should support it, for example PostreSQL does but Mysql doesn't...